# Menu Entry for Game jar

Tags: lubuntu

I have a game in a executable .jar file and I want to add an entry to the start menu under games section with the icon of the game etc.How can I do that ?I am not confident about editing or using sudo.I use Lubuntu 18.04 as my single OS.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://launchpad.net/menulibre Menulibre is GUI tool that will accomplish what you need.To install run

sudo apt-get install menulibre

Open the application,click on the games section in the left side and click on the + then add launcher.In the command line add the following: java -jar /path to your game.jar/.Save and exit.If you want to add an icon image click the box on the top left beside "New Launcher" and select any picture.[image: Menulibre]

Comment: Thanks,this is what I needed.